# Is pyspark.sql grouped data putting each group into a single partition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When I use group aggregate pandas UDFs in GroupedData.agg(), how will this UDF be applied to the data in a single group? I would think that spark is first partitioning the data such that each group is sent to a single executor (i.e. not split), and then each group is locally processed by the udf.

Is this correct?

If so, what are the things to look out for? If one group is too large for an executor, will there be a memory error?

Comment: Make sure to have right sized partitions after shuffle by tuning spark.sql.shuffle.partition count ..

Comment: Check counts on individual groups to just have a view about how severely data is skewed ... and keep executor memory enough to hold worst possible grouped dataset by estimating size based on counts.

Comment: check other api's like aggregateByKey or reduceByKey for better memory utilization